# Javascript not functioning when conducting local testing

Tags: javascript, html, httpserver, simplehttpserver

Good Morning/Afternoon/Evening all,

I'm working on developing a fairly simple webpage, I have index.html setting up the appearance of the page and in the header I have a link to a js file:

```
<script src="toOutput.js"></script>
```

Later on I have a button that's linked to a function in the js file:

```
<input type="button" id="update" name="update" value="Update" onclick="getInput()"><br>
```

I know the connection between these function is set up correctly because I have it running publicly on a separate system while I continue development. However, as I'm trying to conduct further testing locally for the life of me I cannot get the javascript to run. I've tried using the npm module http-server to host and I can navigate to the page which appropriately pulls and uses style.css, and if I view the source code I can click on toOutput.js and I see the code, but when I click the update button the code doesn't run. I've also tried using 'python3 -m http.server 8000' again I can see the page and style.css loads, and the javascript is there, but won't execute. Finally I tried copying the environment I have set up running the page publicly which uses apache2 and points at the appropriate directory. Once again, I can navigate to the page when I use this method, all the code is there, and still the javascript does not run. I've also cleared the cache in the browser a bunch of times and tried other methods for calling the javascript, like adding an event listener within it, none of it has worked.

What am I missing?

Comment: Hi! Does your browser console output anything? Open the browser development tools (for example, F12 in Chrome).

Comment: In the console when I click update I get "Uncaught ReferenceError: getInput is not defined" but I believe I've called the script correctly in the head, and I know the browser is getting the script because in view page source I can navigate to it and see the code so I don't know why.

Comment: Ok seems reasonable. If you have the browser console open, can you call `getInput()` directly yourself? If the function was loaded you would be able to. There are no other errors before you click the button?